# Top users list of answerers that includes post count

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer, top-users

I wanted a [query like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326093) that ranks by answer vote count for a given tag but that also includes a column with the number of answers.

Essentially a replica of the [topusers page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/topusers) list for all-time answerers showing more than top 20.

(There's also [this excellent query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327322), but it adds TMI for the above simple use case.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is that [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1307991).

Notice I join the tables posts, posttags and tags. In the columns I sum the score, once for all posts and once only for posts that are not community wiki. I also included the vote split in up and downvotes and the number of acceptvotes.

```
select rank() over(order by sum(p.score) desc
                          , sum(acceptvotes) desc
                          , sum(upvotes) desc
                          , sum(downvotes) desc) [rank]
     , p.owneruserid [User Link]
     , sum(p.score) [total score]
     , sum(acceptvotes) [accept votes]
     , sum(upvotes) [up votes]
     , sum(downvotes) [down votes]
     , sum(case when CommunityOwnedDate is null then p.score else 0 end) [score without cw]
     , count(p.id)  [answer count]
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.parentid
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
left outer join (
  select v.postid 
       , sum(case when v.votetypeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) acceptvotes
       , sum(case when v.votetypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) upvotes
       , sum(case when v.votetypeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) downvotes
  from votes v
  where v.votetypeid in (1,2,3)
  group by postid  
) votesplit  on votesplit.postid = p.id
where p.posttypeid = 2 -- Answers
and t.tagname = ##tag:string?data-explorer##
group by p.owneruserid
order by sum(p.score) desc
       , sum(acceptvotes) desc
       , sum(upvotes) desc
       , sum(downvotes) desc
```

when run today for the data-explorer tag this will be your result:

[image]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the very useful [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the awesome [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Answer (score 3):

I've modified that query by adding

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(Posts.Id)) AS [Number of answers],
```

and making the join to the Votes table an outer join, since answers which aren't voted upon count as well. [This](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1307996/top-users-for-a-tag?tagName=maven) is the result:

[image]